# Can't find the correct collation/charset for my form

Tags: database, character-encoding, collation

I've setup a simple bootstrap page to insert rows in my db, but I can't get the db to save in the right format/charset.

I want it to support multiple languages since I'm saving beer names from different countries, but even when I set the collation to a specific language on the affected rows and only submit letters from that charset, it still doesn't save the letters right.

Here's a table I exported from the db:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Favorites` (
  `fav_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(55) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `fk_beer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fav_comment` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fav_id`),
  KEY `FK_FavBeer_Beer` (`fk_beer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

I get confused by the fact that (in PhpMyAdmin) I can set collations on both db, table and row.

Where and what collation is right for my db?

EDIT:

It may be because I'm using ajax to send the form:

I have the following settings:

contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Used utf8_decode in the php file..